# Using elasticsearch with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, stemming, mongoosastic

I'm using [mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) which is based on the [official ElasticSearch client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js). Mongoosastic is a plugin, which allows me to use ElasticSearch with MongoDB. I've done basic queries like

```
NodesModel.search({
    "query_string": {
        "query": "developed"
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(err, JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

and they work fine. However now I'm trying to enable stemming feature of elasticsearch. I've used [the stemming example](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html) from the official ES docs, but can't get it working with mongoosastic. I've tried

```
NodesModel.search({
    "query_string": {
        "query": "developed"
    },

    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "my_stemmer": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "light_german"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(err, JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

The output is the following:

```
    { [Error: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all sha
rds failed; shardFailures {[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][0]: SearchParseExcep
tion[[nodess][0]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed
 to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"analy
sis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","lo
wercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"light_
german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but go
t START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][1]: SearchParseExcep
tion[[nodess][1]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed
 to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"analy
sis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","lo
wercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"light_
german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but go
t START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][2]: SearchParseExcep
tion[[nodess][2]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed
 to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"analy
sis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","lo
wercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"light_
german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but go
t START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][3]: SearchParseExcep
tion[[nodess][3]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed
 to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"analy
sis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","lo
wercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"light_
german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but go
t START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][4]: SearchParseExcep
tion[[nodess][4]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed
 to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"analy
sis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","lo
wercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"light_
german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but go
t START_OBJECT "index"]; }]]
  message: 'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all s
hards failed; shardFailures {[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][0]: SearchParseExc
eption[[nodess][0]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Fail
ed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"ana
lysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","
lowercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"ligh
t_german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but
got START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][1]: SearchParseExc
eption[[nodess][1]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Fail
ed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"ana
lysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","
lowercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"ligh
t_german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but
got START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][2]: SearchParseExc
eption[[nodess][2]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Fail
ed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"ana
lysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","
lowercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"ligh
t_german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but
got START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][3]: SearchParseExc
eption[[nodess][3]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Fail
ed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"ana
lysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","
lowercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"ligh
t_german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but
got START_OBJECT "index"]; }{[zn4Omh8tRy-ml0K0lRpMig][nodess][4]: SearchParseExc
eption[[nodess][4]: query[_all:developed],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Fail
ed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"developed"},"index":{"ana
lysis":{"analyzer":{"my_analyzer":{"tokenizer":"standard","filter":["standard","
lowercase","my_stemmer"]}},"filter":{"my_stemmer":{"type":"stemmer","name":"ligh
t_german"}}}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but
got START_OBJECT "index"]; }]' } undefined
```

as I see the mongoosastic passes the first parameter to ES nodejs client like this:

```
schema.statics.search = function(query, options, cb){
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      cb = arguments[1]
      options = {}
    }

    options.hydrateOptions = options.hydrateOptions || defaultHydrateOptions || {};

    if (query === null)
      query = undefined

    var model = this
      , esQuery = {
        body: {
          query: query
        },
        index: options.index || indexName,
        type:  options.type  || typeName
      }
     if (options.highlight) {
        esQuery.body.highlight = options.highlight;
     }
 .......
```

So my question is how I can get the stemming working?

Answer (score -1):

i would not recommend using a plugin on top of another plugin.

Also imo elasticsearch should not be used as a database, but more like an indexing service.

Give the original low-level package a try, its easy to learn and works fine.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch